# How can I extend a model with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model

I want to have a general product model that has basic info like name, description, sku number etc. I also want to have another model that is a specific type of product that essentially extends the product model. For example: I'd like to have a clothing model that has additional columns like color, size, etc.

What is the best practice to implement this? I am thinking polymorphism or Single Table Inheritance. Maybe I am going down the wrong path??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single Table Inheritance ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)) is a common approach. Another is to use modules for shared functionality.

Here is an example of using modules.

```
module Product
  def method_for_all_products
    # ...
  end
end

class Clothing < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Product

  def clothing_specific_method
    # ...
  end
end

class Furniture < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Product
end
```